How can i remove quotes from a return column name that is a STRING; SQL
I am  new to BIgQuery(google), with 1% experience, this is my situation.
UPDATE celigo.Contact.Company
SET {{data.0.propertyName}} = {{data.0.propertyValue}}
WHERE Id = {{data.0.objectId}}

I am getting an error on the 2nd line, {{data.0.propertyName}} is returning a string, column_name are suppose to be non-string.
Sample data:
"data": [
    {
      "objectId": 123,
      "changeSource": "CRM",
      "propertyName": "Email",
      "propertyValue": "sample-value"
    }

My goal is to turn this
UPDATE celigo.Contact.Company
SET 'Email' = 'sample-value'
WHERE Id = 123

to
UPDATE celigo.Contact.Company
SET Email = 'sample-value'
WHERE Id = 123

removing the quote from Email using sql method if it is doable
Tried using the REPLACE SQL method next to SET and that did not work
I tried DECLARE a variable and then use REPLACE, and that did not work.

I was able to find a workaround for the situationship I was in.
UPDATE celigo.Contact.Company
SET Email = CASE
    WHEN {{data.0.propertyName}} = 'Email' THEN {{data.0.propertyValue}}   
    ELSE Email
END,
Company = CASE
    WHEN {{data.0.propertyName}} = 'Name' THEN {{data.0.propertyValue}}
    ELSE Name
END
WHERE Id = CAST({{data.0.objectId}} AS STRING);

So, before updating a column, I will check to see what property has changed. If a CASE is matched, it will be updated; otherwise, it will ignore the changes and not update

I am still open if there are more options or other workaround on this. Thank you in advance.
